# What do you call someone who is consistently alternative.

Tags: psychology, personality

I know of someone who consistently likes identifying with disorders or minority groups. This person, to date, is diagnosed (very dubiously) as Aspbergers, ADHD, depression, anxiety, and transgender. In addition, this person has identified bisexual, pansexual, atheist, and pantheist at different points. Although after frequently talking with this individual its clear that their symptoms are mild at best for each of these things (aside from Atheism). This person expresses a distaste for popular things, simply because they're popular.  Overall this person consistently shows an obsession with being alternative, and cannot reconcile being normal in any aspect.  They're a mega-hipster of some sort. A word for this person, or an psychological disorder that justifies this sort of behavior is what I'm looking for.

Comment: anti, dissident, nonconformist, recusant, refractory, balky, etc.

Comment: The way you put it, I doubt anyone can come up with the right word for such a personality.   Suggestions may be presented and you may even choose one, but a psychiatrist would need a few sessions to come to the right word.

Comment: I would consider the words disputant,dissentient, oppugnant, or oppositionist.

Comment: @anonymous - I too consider Taitrnator's words to be disputant, dissentient, oppugnant, and oppositionist.

Comment: How about "polypathological"?

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few good suggestions in comments, allow me to put forward two more. Such a person could be described as a **contrarian:**

> a person who takes an opposite or different position or attitude from other people - [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrarian)

They could also be **countercultural:**

> [*adjectival form of counterculture*:] a culture with values and mores that run counter to those of established society - *[Ibid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterculture)*.